# Open in Terminal in Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, terminal, raspberry-pi-desktop

How can I get the "Open in Terminal" Option when I right click in Raspbian OS ?

It opens the terminal in the current directory.

Comment: This shall involve configuring the Openbox/LXDE desktop shipped with the Raspberry Pi. That would be complicated, and I'm not sure it's worth your effort. A simple workaround is to navigate to that directory with `pcmanfm` (the default file browser) and hit **F4** or *Tools menu* > *Open Current Folder in Terminal*

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. What are you trying to say?

Answer (score 1):

Openbox right-click menu is normally configured in a file called `menu.xml`, which is located either in `~/.config/openbox/` or somewhere under `/usr/share/` if you don't have the former file.

Find out what the command syntax is for this "Open in Terminal" option on a system where you have it (I'd expect something like `lxterminal --command=%1`), and add this item in the menu of your RPi.